# Hue dashboard search behaving randomly

Tags: search, indexing, solr, dashboard, hue

I am very new to Hue/solr. Just to play around a bit, I extracted the following information into a csv file

```
FileName,DataYear(YYYYMMDD),VENDOR,DEST1,DEST2
```

- Filename contains Vendor,DataYear (separated by _)
- DataYear & Vendor are just derived fields from Filename for easy
  reference
- Dest1 & Dest2 contain full unis paths with '/'

I went to Hue->Search-> (solr) Indexes and uploaded the above CSV file and indexed all fields as text_general (saw in one of the videos that it has to be text_general to make it searchable?).

I created a dashboard (for that index) with a couple of text facts (vendor, datayear) on left and result set on right.

The selection of filters work great and the result set refreshes in the grid.

But, when I type a text (say a vendor name) in the search box, I am expecting all files/records with that vendor name alone to be filtered with vendor name highlighted in the result grid. But, it is not happening.

It is working for some search strings like part of destination paths, file extensions and some vendor names - but not for all.

Is there some basic option or step I missed? Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query you type is the same as in Solr: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax. So you probably need somethnig like 'vendor:Bob*' or tweak the Solr handlers.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am getting the hand of it slowly. It looks like any wild card searches like *vendorname* works with the unique/key field. For others, it needs to be in the SolrQuerySyntax.